# Django migration error when database has custom views

Tags: django, django-orm

Django 3.1.

app folder :  `stocks`

project folder with settings inside:  `main`

I have this model:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    open = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    high = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    low = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    is_regular = models.BooleanField()
    change = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
```

In the SQLite database I have created view `daily_bottoms` from that model using SQliteStudio.

Now I am trying to migrate because added another field. `makemigrations` works fine, but when trying to migrate I get an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: error in view daily_bottoms: no such table: main.stocks_bar
```

If I delete the view then it will migrate , but I would like to avoid that every time.

How to make it work?

Comment: after ```makemigrations```, did you run ```migrate```?

Comment: @Sumithran, yes, thats when i get the error

Answer (score 0):

If your table is not managed by Django you should set

```
 class Meta:
       managed = False
```

on your model as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#managed)

> If False, no database table creation, modification, or deletion
> operations will be performed for this model. This is useful if the
> model represents an existing table or a database view that has been
> created by some other means